# Issue with parentheses when mixing Arabic or Hebrew text with latin

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

How can I mix text from a language that reads from `right to left`, with lating words that reads from `left to right`, without affecting parentheses orientation ?

[image: parentheses direction]

Do I need to use a `Regex` that reconizes caracters from `encoding`, and automatically apply a `direction` & `text-orientation`?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552804/direction-ltr-in-a-rtl-html-page

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that: `unicode-bidi:-moz-plaintext` has resolved it for `firefox` and `unicode-bidi:-webkit-plaintext` for `chrome`.

But, this is an experimental property, it's not yet a standard: [unicode-bidi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi). I wonder what are the other variants of `plaintext` for other browsers.